# How do I update dom-repeat list with new array

Tags: javascript, polymer, redux

So, I am trying to learn Redux. Great library by the way, really easy to grasp.

However, I am using Polymer, and have a todo-list element. In my todo-list element I have a properties definition,

```
properties: {
  items: {
    type: Array,
    notify: true
  }
},
```

and a ready function,

```
ready: function() {
  var that = this;
  store.subscribe(function() {
    var state = store.getState();
    console.log('State have been updated ', state);
    that.items = state.todos;
    that.notifyPath('items', that.items);
    console.log('items ', that.items);
  });

  store.dispatch(actions.requestTodos());
}
```

The Redux part works just fine. In another element (not important) I do a dispatch of an ADD_TODO action, and I receive an update in the function passed to the subscribe function above, and the state is updated.

When reading the documentation for dom-repeat and lists in Polymer it seems as a full update and re-rendering of the list isn't supported, instead the documentation mentions using methods such as pop, push or splice for updating the list (array). But I really don't want that.

Any ideas how to update the list with a new full state? Because right now, the list is updated but not re-rendered, so the changes are not displayed.

Comment: By the way, if you use [es6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) then you don't have to do all of the `var that = this;` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ready: function() {
  var that = this;
  store.subscribe(function() {
    var state = store.getState();
    console.log('State have been updated ', state);
    that.set('items',state.todos.slice());

    console.log('items ', that.items);
  });

  store.dispatch(actions.requestTodos());
}
```

Use the slice() on the list. You insert to this.items state.todos

the problem is that if the state.todo is the same array polymer will not know that the  content is changed. In this way you create new array, And thus polymer will now that the array changed.

Comment: Can't get it to work anyway. Tried to copy the whole state object with Object.assign({}, state) and use instead but doesn't work at all. Do I have to render manually somehow?

Comment: can you give example in jsbin?

Comment: Hi, I eventually found some time to look at this. I ended up rewriting my application from the bottom, and following your example. And it do work now, so I guess I did something fundamentally wrong in my first attempt.

Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure that you always return a new state, and that any properties in that new state are also new. Don't mutate lists that you save on your state, always replace them with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Just make sure that you always return a new state, and that any properties in that new state are also new. Don't mutate lists that you save on your state, always replace them with new ones.

I just want to say that I spent an entire week trying different solutions, and this one worked. Thank you for that answer!

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Please take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: No, it's not a complete answer, but it's a highlight for an answer that took me an entire week to figure out, and and answer 50 pages of different google searched couldn't answer AND that the Polymer documentation didn't bring up.

I made the post to bring up this important issue, and also gave the thread a +1 because the comment brought up something that no other thread has brought up.

Comment: That answer shouldn't be hidden in a comment, but be an answer of its own. It is now.